# AttributeGraph precondition failure: child already attached to new parent

Tags: swift, swiftui

iOS 14.3 xcode 12.3
I get
AttributeGraph precondition failure: child already attached to new parent.
When I
self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()

Comment: can you please share more code. is this a navigation based on a list ?